# AsyncStorage saying 'undefined is not an object'

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am working on a shopping check list and want to save the checked items in local storage. However, setting up AsyncStorage hasnt been working for me saying undefined is not an object

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, CheckBox, AsyncStorage } from 'native-base';

export default class ShoppingListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.saveCheck = this.saveCheck.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem style={styles.table}>
        <CheckBox 
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onPress={this.saveCheck}/>
        <Text>{this.props.item[0]} {this.props.item[1]} {this.props.item[2]}</Text>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }

  // componentWillMount () {
  //   AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.key).then((value) => {
  //      this.setState({checked: value});
  //   }).done();
  // }

  saveCheck () {
    console.log(this.state.checked)
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    AsyncStorage.setItem('checked', JSON.stringify(this.state.checked))
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this without using JSON.stringify since you will be just storing a boolean? Not sure if that's the problem or not just checking..

Comment: yes I did try that, still getting the same error

Comment: How about `JSON.stringify({ checked: this.state.checked })` ?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the line `this.props.key`

See this warning thrown by react-native

[image]

So change your props `'key'` to some other name, then everything should work as expected.

Also import `AsyncStorage` from 'react-native'

Change

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

to

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

and remove AsyncStorage from 'native-base'

Comment: importing from react-native instead of AsyncStorage made it work for me, thanks!

Comment: AsyncStorage is now found by importing this:

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';